# what are the leading XSL-FO implementations? How do I decide among them?

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I'm evaluating PDF rendering technologies. XSL-FO is our chosen path because its an open standard and our source data is XML.  What experiences have people had with the various implementations of XSL-FO?

The implementations I've found so far are:

- [renderX](http://www.renderx.com/)
- [ecrion](http://www.ecrion.com/)
- [Antenna House](http://www.antennahouse.com/)
- [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)

The criteria I'm using to evaluate are: performance, stability, supportability, 
price, template management tools. Also important: good java APIs and ability to run on Unix.

Whatever product we end up choosing, we will also be asked to find consulting services to help us build our templates, so the ability to find developers versed in the the technology is important.

Update:

The Ecrion folks did a [performance comparison](http://www.ecrion.com/Products/XFUltrascale/PerformanceComparisonGraph.aspx)  which is disputed by the [renderX](http://www.ecrion.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=19)
people. However, renderX has so far declined to offer their own benchmarks or tests for comparison. I guess I'll have to run my own benchmarks.

So far I'm leaning toward Ecrion because it supports WordML output, and the renderX guy was kind of rude.

Comment: a long overdue follow up: I ended up rendering our invoices with Apache FOP. There were some minor formatting issues, but they were all solvable. The rendering service I built on FOP was plenty fast for our invoice run of a few thousand invoices once a month. saved about $30k-$40k in licensing fees.

Comment: The ecrion/renderx links are dead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ibex pdf creator](http://www.xmlpdf.com/) is a good XSL-FO engine with Java and .NET implementations.

I have used their Java implementation and it did pretty much everything we needed and was performant.  **Their licensing model is really good**, especially if you are building clients that need XSL-FO processing.  You pay a *per-developer fee*, **not** a *per-client distribution*.

[Antenna House](http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo.htm) and [renderX.](http://www.renderx.com/) are the leaders in the XSL-FO space.  They have great tools and overall support/implementation for the XSL-FO specification.

Regardless of which FO engine you decide on, it is helpful to have several available for development.  **Rendering through different FO engines helps test out your XSL-FO and determine if incorrect output is due to a problem with the rendering engine or with your XSL-FO.**

Comment: Thanks. That's the kind of feedback I was looking for.

Comment: If you are looking for XSL-FO consulting services and training, Ken Holman offers both and is fantastic.  He helped create a truly extensible (XSL-FO) stylesheet library that generated PDF and HTML output for a project of mine.  I can't say enough good things about his work.  http://cranesoftwrights.com

Comment: a bit of spam: check udemy.com/practical-transformation-using-xslt-and-xpath (5 hours of free videos) and cranesoftwrights.com/training/index.htm#pdfbooks (more than a thousand pages of book text).

Answer (score 2):

Ecrion has the most advanced report designer. It's way above Antenna's tool, and you can see the actual XSL-FO that is being edited. This is important because you can use Ecrion's Designer with all XSL-FO formatters including FOP. Other vendors are trying to achieve a vendor lock-in to their own FO formatter.

Answer (score 1):

[Antennahouse](http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo.htm) is another major XSL-FO implementation:

Comment: Thanks, they also seem like a major player in the rendering field. One thing they don't include is a Visual template designer, which the other products do include. They seem to have a solid offering otherwise.

Comment: correction. I just met with the AntennaHouse guy, who was very helpful. They do indeed offer a template creation tool called ReportDesigner

Answer (score 0):

Late entry, but to complete: I'm using XML2PDF Workstation from www.alt-soft.com
 - it's fast, cheap and does the job, even SVG and Bookmarks.